# Haskell, I need help as I can't seem to work out what I have done wrong. (Basic)

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and am trying to learn using things like learn you a Haskell. Can someone explain what is wrong with my code as I don't really know how to read error messages yet. All I can tell so far is that the let statements aren't correct but I need them to work somehow because without them the (show (typeOf numone/numtwo)) only shows the type of either 'numone' or 'numtwo' and not the inputted values from the getLine.

What I am trying to do is compare the inputs and show the types of the inputs but this is as far I can go without some help.

```
import Data.Typeable

main = do  
  putStrLn "Enter two statements."  
  numone <- getLine
  numtwo <- getLine

putStrLn $ ("You entered " ++ show numone ++ (show (typeOf numone)) ++ " and " ++ show numone ++ (show (typeOf numone)))

  let numone = getLine
  let numtwo = getLine

if numone == numtwo

  then  

    putStrLn $ "They are the same and their types are " ++ (show (typeOf     numone)) ++ " and " ++ (show (typeOf numtwo))

  else
putStrLn $ "They are not the same"
```

Error message;

```
• No instance for (Eq (IO String)) arising from a use of ‘==’
• In the expression: numone == numtwo
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    if numone == numtwo then
        putStrLn
          $ "They are the same and their types are "
              ++ (show (typeOf numone)) ++ " and " ++ (show (typeOf numtwo))
    else
        putStrLn $ "They are not the same"
  In the expression:
    do putStrLn "Enter two statements."
       numone <- getLine
       numtwo <- getLine
       putStrLn
         $ ("You entered "
              ++
                show numone
                  ++
                    (show (typeOf numone))
                      ++ " and " ++ show numone ++ (show (typeOf numone)))
       ....
      |
   10 |   if numone == numtwo
      |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The output should be something like (depending on the input of getLine);

```
>    You entered A123[String] and B456[String]

>    They are the same and their types are [String] and [String]     
     or 
     They are not the same
```

Comment: Please format your code in a more readable format. Also, the lines `let numone = getLine` `let numtwo = getLine` will not typecheck because:
1. `numone` and `numtwo` are already bound to variables, which are immutable in Haskell.
2. They have type `IO String`.

Comment: Your `let`s will not get executed, you only *encapsulate* the `getLine` logic into a variable. But regardless, the mistake is that you write *imperative code* in Haskell syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is exactly as shown in the question, then the first problem is indentation.

Indentation matters in Haskell (like in Python), unless you use the `{ ... ; ... ; ... }` syntax.

The second problem is that `getLine` is an action in the IO-monad, so you can't use `let`, but must use a monadic binding.

Oh, and the second binding overrides the first. So while using the name a second time is not wrong, it's bad style.

The third thing (it's not really a problem) is that the code as written will assign static types to `numone` and `numtwo` - it's not somehow like entering different values will change their type. `getLine` has type

```
getLine :: IO String
```

so you'll *always* see `[Char]` (aka `String`) as the type.

The fourth problem is that you used `numone` twice in the first output, instead of `numone` and `numtwo`.

**Edit**

I completely removed the second input (the former `let`-statements) according to the comments.

Here's the corrected program:

```
import Data.Typeable

main :: IO ()
main = do  
  putStrLn "Enter two statements."  
  numone <- getLine
  numtwo <- getLine
  putStrLn $ ("You entered " ++ show numone ++ (show (typeOf numone)) ++ " and " ++ show numtwo ++ (show (typeOf numtwo)))
  if numone == numtwo then 
    putStrLn $ "They are the same and their types are " ++ (show (typeOf numone)) ++ " and " ++ (show (typeOf numtwo))
  else
    putStrLn $ "They are not the same"
  return ()
```

Example session fro `ghci`:

```
*Main> main
Enter two statements.
A123
B456
You entered "A123"[Char] and "B456"[Char]
They are not the same
*Main> main
Enter two statements.
A123
A123
You entered "A123"[Char] and "A123"[Char]
They are the same and their types are [Char] and [Char]
*Main>
```

So that should do what you want.

Let me emphasize again: You'll *always* get `[Char]` as the type, no matter what you do. You can't assign dynamic types based on input. And in general, the Haskell typesystem is static; while there are some advanced constructions like `Data.Typeable`, I wouldn't recommend them for beginners. Your mental image should be "when I compile the program, the Haskell typechecker will assign a single static type to every subexpression". You can actually ask the typechecker for those by using `:t` in the REPL:

```
*Main> :t getLine
getLine :: IO String
```

Comment: the thing is, this still only shows the type of 'numone' or 'numtwo' and not the values inputted by the getLine. also in this there are four inputs and not two which is what I am working with

Comment: If you want two inputs and not four, then use two inputs ... or phrased differently: What purpose should the `let` in your code serve? And if you want to have the values, don't use `typeof`, but `show numone` etc. It may help if you edit the question and clearly state *what you want the program to do*.

Comment: okay I will edit it and show exactly what the output should be