# Check type signature of inputted value and compare part of values

Tags: haskell

If I was to use '( ) <- getLine', how would I check the type signature of the value on output through a putStrLn?

```
 numone <- getLine 

 (show (typeOf numone))
```

When I use this it checks and prints the type signature of the word 'numone' and not what is inputted through the getLine function. Is there a workaround for this?

Also;

How would I compare a certain part of two inputted strings? 
If I was to enter A12345 and A12335, I am looking for an output of "They both contain A123 at the start". So far I am using
`if numone == numtwo
  then

    putStrLn $ "They are the same and their types are " ++ (show (typeOf numone)) ++ " and " ++ (show (typeOf numtwo))
  else
    putStrLn $ "They are not the same"`

> The reason I wanted to be able to print what type of the inputted values were is to show wether or not the values were the same along with if they have same type. So A123 [String] is not the same as B123 [String] but as I've been told, that is simply not possible with how I want it.

Comment: I think you do not really understand how Haskell works. Haskell is *statically typed*. That means that at *compile time*. The type of all variables is perfectly known. The value that is written at runtime, does not matter. If `numone` has type `Int`, then if I write `1` it will produce an `Int`, if I write `"foobar"`, then it will raise an error, since the idea is that it has to be an `Int`.

Comment: Why would anyone want to answer the question if you're just going to delete it?

Comment: I am very new to Haskell yes. So how would I change the initial type before the compile time to check the type of an inputted value?

Comment: @Stefan: but an inputted value has no type, it is only a string, a stream of characters. If I write `42` I have *not* written the number 42. I have only written a `4` followed by a `2`. Whether you, your program or anyone else sees that as the number `42` or two random characters, or perhaps a tree, an octal number, the grayscale of a 2x1 image, etc. Is a matter of *interpretation*.

Comment: I have answered the question as asked, because I think the answer may be useful to somebody else in the future. But given your apparent level of expertise I do not expect my answer to be useful to you; I apologize for that. I think the question is pretty irretrievably broken at the moment. You'll need to give some context about *why you think you need this* before we can redirect you to an appropriate solution. You *probably* just want to define a small grammar and write a parser, e.g. with parsec or alex+happy, but it's not super clear yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell, I need help as I can't seem to work out what I have done wrong. (Basic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368687/haskell-i-need-help-as-i-cant-seem-to-work-out-what-i-have-done-wrong-basic)

Comment: I don't understand your question. `getLine` is type `IO String`, so `numone` is going to be type `String`, every single time: it's a string containing the characters in the line that you got. If you know those characters are digits, you can convert the string to a numeric type using `read`, in which case you'd have to specify what type you want it to parse as (otherwise the compiler will complain). But in that case you still know the type beforehand, so there's no reason to check it at runtime. Maybe if you told us what you were trying to do, that would be helpful.

Comment: `You entered A123[String] and B456[String]
They are the same and their types are [String] and [String]     
     or 
     They are not the same`Thats what I want it to show

Comment: @Stefan So you want to read two lines and check if they're the same? You already know they have the same type (they're both `String`). You can check if the values are the same using `==`.

Comment: Well more specifically I want to be able to check if parts of two lines are the same or not. As simply as I can, 2018 and 2019 both share 20 then would print;  'They are of the same millennium . This is the end goal, but I guess seeing as what I initially asked for isn't possible, may I have help with that instead but not a straight answer as I am wanting to learn the steps to do so.

Comment: @Stefan "check if parts of two lines are the same" This is very different from what you say in your question. Where does type comparison come in? Are you checking for arbitrary similar substrings, or do the lines have some sort of format you're working within? Do you always expect dates, and do you check for anything other than if they're the same millennium?

Comment: @Stefan As I said before, I think you should edit your question to explain *what you're trying to do*. As in, what is the purpose of the program you're writing? Where do the lines you're reading come from, and what information do you need to extract from them, and why? What are some example inputs and expected outputs? Contextual information like that is extremely important, because if you don't provide it, we don't actually know what you're asking, and we can't answer properly.

Comment: If what I am asking help for is not clear within the edit please let me know.

Comment: "The reason I wanted to be able to print what type of the inputted values were is to show wether or not the values [...] have same type" So you want to know if they're the same type so you can know if they're the same type? But why? What is the goal here? Can you give examples of input lines and the types you expect them to have? Can you tell us what you're doing with these values after you figure out their types? What are the requirements for the program? Is it just practice for you, or is it an assignment, or is it meant to do something useful? Context helps us understand.

Comment: "as I've been told, that is simply not possible with how I want it." I think the problem is you haven't explained how you want it. The only example you've given is that `A123[String]` and `B456[String]` are the same type and not the same value. Is `A123[String]` the actual contents of the line, or is the line `A123` and the type is `String`? What would a line containing a non-string look like? More examples would be helpful. If you clarify what it is you actually want, we can then tell you whether it's possible.

Comment: I wanted to know if they the values inputted were the same through comparison and to show what types they are. This is just practice for me as I'm trying to learn. Ignoring the part about showing the types, my question is, how do I compare specific parts of two different strings? I'd like to know what I can add to my code to be able to do that as right now I can only compare the two values as a whole.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain it so I will use an example.

A car registration plate shows the year the car was made along with other details.
If I was to compare two near identical cars and wanted to make sure I new which one was which I would look at the registration plate. My code would hopefully be able to show car A was made in year (17) and car B was made in (18). If both cars had registration numbers A17 ABCD and A18 ABCD then if you input those registration numbers into my code, it could tell them apart with a print statement.

I hope this clears it up a little bit.

Comment: Good, we're making progress. So if I understand, what you're looking for now is a way to compare two arbitrary strings and point out any similarities/differences between them, is that correct? In that case, you're going to want some kind of [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm (the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm can also be helpful). There may be a library on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/) you can use. Or you may want to try writing the code yourself, that could be good practice.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the LCS algorithm checks all common elements of the strings. Is there anyway to use that algorithm to check a specific part of a string like in the car registration?

Comment: I think this has been suggested previously, but: if the strings have some significance for you beyond merely being a list of characters then you can *parse* them to extract that meaning. For instance, `data LicensePlate = LicensePlate { year :: String, number :: String }` and a function `parseLicensePlate :: String -> LicensePlate` (of your own devising). Then, once you have a `LicensePlate`, you can compare its parts separately.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [GHC API](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc) to compile (including typecheck) an arbitrary chunk of code given as a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find the type of a value in a program, since Haskell is statically typed.

Instead, use GHCi:

```
> ghci
Prelude> :t "Hello!"
"Hello!" :: [Char]
Prelude> :t 12.3
12.3 :: Fractional a => a
Prelude> :t Just (*)
Just (*) :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a -> a)
```

Comment: But OP *is* getting the type of the value. He's complaining that the type is `[Char]` when he doesn't want it to be. If he did `numOne <- getLine` and then `:t numOne` in GHCi, the result would still be `[Char]`, so nothing changed.

Comment: In that case, how would I assign a value from `getLine` into a variable that I could test with `:t`

Comment: @Stefan In GHCi you could do so by doing `numOne <- getLine` and then `:t numOne` (outside of GHCi, you can't use `:t`), but as I said in my previous comment, the result of that will be exactly the same as the result of `typeOf`: it will always be `[Char]`. `getLine` won't ever give you anything other than a string.